# Electron autoUpdater proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am using:

- Electron 1.7.9
- Aurelia

I have a problem with the electron proxy setting, it doesn't work with [autoUpdater](https://www.electron.build/auto-update). On the main process I have this configuration :

```
session.defaultSession.setProxy({
    proxyRules : proxyString
 }, function () {
    console.log("proxy ok")
 });
```

This works in the entire electron app. I can see the logs on squid. AutoUpdater should use Electron Chrome Network API but in my case this not works, the method `checkForUpdates` of AutoUpdater bypass the proxy. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: frankenstein, did you solve this anyhow?

Comment: Please try to set your proxy by using ```mainWindow.webContents.session.setProxy```

Answer (score 1):

setProxy is now a Promise. So now you need to put the last function into the .then() function. I hope this comment helps other people. this work for me:

`window.webContents.session.setProxy({ proxyString }).then(() =>  {console.log("proxyok")}).catch((err) => console.error(err));`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).